# eMMC request timeout error

Tags: drivers, block-device, sd-card, mmc

We have a custom embedded board with a 4GB eMMC chip connected.
We see the following error while emmc read/write test on the eMMC device:

```
mmc0: request with tag: 16 flags: 0x2000000002469030 timed out
```

Can anyone suggest why this timeout may have occurred ?
Kernel version:4.9.125